# Flutter error: List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:166:60)

Tags: android, flutter

Today i upgraded flutter to latest version and now i can't build and start app at all.

Error is thrown when using `flutter run` command and on `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...`.

This is error:

> Unhandled exception:
> Crash when compiling null, at character offset null: RangeError
> (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
> #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:166:60)
> #1      Class.superclassConstraints (package:kernel/ast.dart:1101:73)
> #2      ClassBuilderImpl.checkMixinApplication (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/class_builder.dart:1402:51)
> #3      SourceLoader.checkMixins (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:1093:19)
> #4      KernelTarget.buildOutlines. (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:333:14)
>
> #5      KernelTarget.buildOutlines. (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart)
> #6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:24)
> #7      KernelTarget.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:301:12)
> #8      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta. (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:269:52)
>
> #9      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta. (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart)
> #10     CompilerContext.runInContext.. (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:123:46)
> #11     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:223:31)
> #12     CompilerContext.runInContext. (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:123:19)
> #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
> #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
> #15     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
> #16     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1550:10)
> #17     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:12)
> #18     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:206:20)
> #19     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:69:46)
> #20     FrontendCompiler.compile. (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:526:59)
> #21     new Future. (dart:async/future.dart:175:37)
> #22     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
> #23     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
> #24     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
> #25     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
> #26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
> #27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
> #28     _CustomZone.bindCallback. (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
> #29     Timer._createTimer. (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
> #30     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
> #31     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
> #32     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
>
> #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:166:60)
> #1      Class.superclassConstraints (package:kernel/ast.dart:1101:73)
> #2      ClassBuilderImpl.checkMixinApplication (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/class_builder.dart:1402:51)
> #3      SourceLoader.checkMixins (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:1093:19)
> #4      KernelTarget.buildOutlines. (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:333:14)
>
> #5      KernelTarget.buildOutlines. (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart)
> #6      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:24)
> #7      KernelTarget.buildOutlines (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:301:12)
> #8      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta. (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:269:52)
>
> #9      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta. (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart)
> #10     CompilerContext.runInContext.. (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:123:46)
> #11     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:223:31)
> #12     CompilerContext.runInContext. (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:123:19)
> #13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
> #14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
> #15     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
> #16     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1550:10)
> #17     CompilerContext.runInContext (package:front_end/src/fasta/compiler_context.dart:122:12)
> #18     IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:206:20)
> #19     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:69:46)
> #20     FrontendCompiler.compile. (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:526:59)
> #21     new Future. (dart:async/future.dart:175:37)
> #22     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
> #23     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
> #24     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
> #25     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
> #26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13) the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly. the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
>
> #28     _CustomZone.bindCallback. (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:23)
> #29     Timer._createTimer. (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
> #30     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:397:19)
> #31     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:428:5)
> #32     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

I've tried `flutter clean` but nothing. Also i tried to pull again code from git and run `flutter pub get` but still nothing.

This is info from `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.2 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision bbfbf1770c (8 days ago), 2020-08-13 08:33:09 -0700
    • Engine revision 9d5b21729f
    • Dart version 2.9.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.47.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.2

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi Note 5 (mobile) • 41e4e25 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
```

Thank you guys in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this error by reinstalling flutter. So just delete flutter folder, download latest from their site and extract it to same place where old folder was.